# How to copy all the fields (all the columns and rows) in an .mpp file to Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an .mpp file which I need to get in an Excel format. That is, all the column headings  in the .mpp file should be copied as the column headings of the new Excel sheet and all the data for each column in the .mpp file should be under each column in the excel sheet.

Comment: From the below link I got code to copy the task fields from .mpp file to excel ,but I want to copy all the fields even customized columns from .mpp file [stackoverflow.com/questions/9380117/… –

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which kind of file .mpp is but if it's a text-like file with some columns you can open it with Excel without using a vba script.

On Windows : right click on the file, select "Open With", then select the "Excel" program.
An other way to do it is to open Excel and to open your file with it.

In both cases, Excel will ask you some information on the format of your file.

Hope this was helpfull.

Comment: .mpp file we can not open in "Excel" and .mpp file are not pure text like files, its Microsoft Project Plan. From the below link  I got code to copy the task fields from .mpp file to excel but I want to copy all the fields even customized columns from .mpp file   [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380117/how-to-copy-tasks-data-from-microsoft-project-plan-to-excel]